# Tool for viewing used and free memory on windows system

Tags: windows, memory

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to see all of the memory used by by Windows XP/2003 machine.  I know that Process Explorer and others will show you what memory is being used by each process, but I need a full graphical view of all used and unused memory on my machine.  I have seen an app that does this but cannot remember the name.  Anyone know of a tool like this?

Answer (score 4):

Task Manager displays this on the *Performance* tab. In Process Explorer you can view that when clicking on one of the graphs at the top of the window.

Then there is the Resource monitor (`resmon`):

[image: Resource Monitor]

as well as the Performance monitor (`perfmon`):

[image: Performance Monitor]

Comment: +1 Windows has a lot of useful built-in tools, especially when it comes to performance monitoring.

Comment: That is one funky looking process list.

Comment: Home-made font, called “Don't expose what processes I'm running” ;-) Not everyone needs to know what I'm doing here and blurring is boring.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a two in one package: [Rizone Memory Booster](http://www.rizonetech.com/?download=memboost.zip)

This shows the memory, and optimizes it too, and is portable [does not need to be installed.]

Answer (score 0):

The best tool that I've seen is [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). You can configure it to display a wide range of memory info.