# What's using up my memory?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I already know what's causing this -- it's the driver for [FancyCache](http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/fancy-cache/index.html), which I'd installed myself.

But as you can see, nothing in the screenshot tells me anything about this. I just happen to know.

#### So the question is, if I *didn't* know this, how would I figure out what's using up so much of my RAM?

(For reference: It's currently 1.7 GiB used, and the "missing" amount -- for FancyCache -- is 512 MiB. Clearly, that extra half-gigabyte not showing up anywhere I can see below.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What makes you think your memory *is used up*?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Uhm, feel free to substitute whatever word suits your fancy. Regardless of the terminology you like, though, I think the question is pretty clear.

Comment: I'm not arguing terminology. I just see 72% of your memory unused (that's what I assume, I'm not familiar with Process Hacker). I'm confused about what the problem is.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Oh. The problem is that it's normally 1.2 GiB (i.e. when FancyCache is off), not 1.7 GiB. So I know the where the extra memory is going, but my question is, how would I figure this out if I didn't already know the answer?

Comment: I usually start with [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx). Also, in case you haven't seen it already: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that before. Regarding RAMMap, I can see there's 564M for memory mapped files (mostly standby, probably what's causing this), and 939M that's process private (probably normal). Other than that, I see nothing over (or close to) 500 MB. But that's all it tells me, which is frankly, not much -- I still have no idea what driver is responsible for it. (Nothing in the Processes tab or the File tabs points to the problem either; they all seem fine.)

Comment: Just out of Curiosity, how much Ram does the OS see?  I mean the total listed at Physical Memory is 6.12gb?  From what I can read FancyCache is like a Ram Disk that loads before Windows, no?

Comment: @BonGart: No, FancyCache is just that -- a cache. According to Task Manager (and PH and everywhere else I look), yes, it's 6126 MB. I installed 4 GiB of it myself, and I know there's a 2 GiB module in there, so I'm pretty sure that's correct. :-) (I don't have any page files.)

Comment: What does Process Explorer show? Try enabling all of the memory columns and look for something that stands out.

Comment: @Synetech: Let me quit all my programs/services and screenshot it... gimme a couple minutes.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I can’t run the latest version of PH on the system I’m using at the moment, so I cannot tell you which column to use, but I stand by my answer that you need to look at a different memory column. Check them all to see which one has a big spike.

Comment: @Synetech: No worries. I also stand by my response that there's no spike like you claim. :-) Now I get [this](http://imgur.com/PP92X) when FancyCache is off, and [this](http://imgur.com/ECjXY) when it's on. (Notice the "Physical Usage" on the status bar changes dramatically, but nothing else does.)

Comment: @Mehrdad, ah interesting. I see your confusion. `o.O` Hmm, there *must* be a way to account for it; I cannot imagine that FancyCache uses rootkit techniques, but then again, I don’t see anything related to FancyCache at all, so it must indeed be hiding… Check `services.msc`; is there a FancyCache service?

Comment: Lol. No, it's a driver. I'm pretty sure it's not using any abnormal techniques, although I obviously don't know for certain.

Comment: Ah, okay. I’m not sure how you can monitor the memory usage of a driver. I just checked RootRepeal, but it only shows the size of the drive image, not its memory usage. RAMMap specifically mentions drivers in the description, so if it is not showing it…

Comment: @Synetech: Yeah. I don't usually ask this type of question unless it's already stumped me pretty hard. :P

Comment: Try this: (1) open ProcExp, (2) click `System`, (3) *View->Show Lower Pane*, (4) *Lower Pane View->DLLs*, (5) enable memory columns (of lower pane). Now look for FancyCache.

Comment: @Synetech: Size: 0x22000. I'm pretty sure that's just the image size. Everything else (WS-stuff, except Base) is zero, not just for FancyCache but for everything else too.

Comment: Hmmm, getting the memory usage of a driver may not be easy. I cannot find any tools that let you do this, and even writing your [may be difficult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395569/measuring-memory-use-of-device-drivers-in-windows)—and require (anti-)rootkit techniques.

Comment: @Synetech: I know there's `ExAllocatePoolWithTag`, so there might be tags I could look at. Trouble is, I have no idea (1) what tool to use for that, or (2) how to read the tags. :-)

Comment: Like I said, you may have to “roll your own” or ask around to see if you can provoke the curiosity of a dev with low-level DDK experience enough to convince them to write one. `;-)` But don’t look at me, my low-level hardware experience is quite rusty; I’ve been writing MFC dialog apps for the past few years. I’m afraid I’m out of ideas at the moment (though I’ll try running some tests the next time I’m using Windows 7). +1 for stumping me though.

Comment: As a general rule, if I understand correctly, Windows simply does not keep track of which device driver allocated any particular chunk of memory.  So the answer is: there's no way to tell, except perhaps by a process of trial and error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find what's eating up all of my system's memory?](http://superuser.com/questions/437918/how-do-i-find-whats-eating-up-all-of-my-systems-memory)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Why are you marking this as a duplicate when we already figured out RAMMap isn't helping us?

Comment: @Mehrdad, this question now has a link to the other question in which he answered.

Comment: @Synetech: Is there something in his answer that I'm not seeing? Because the only diagnostic tool I see in his answer is RAMMap.

Comment: @Mehrdad, don't worry; unless a future version of RAMMap adds the ability to measure drivers, then it has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it looks as if I was wrong; there is a way to monitor memory allocations by device drivers, using [Driver Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545448%28v=vs.85%29).  This tool is built into all current versions of Windows.  Although it was designed and documented for programmers to debug device driver problems, there seems to be no reason you couldn't use it to find which device driver is using the "missing" memory.

You can bring up the [Driver Verifier Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545459%28v=vs.85%29) simply by typing "verifier" in the Start Menu or at a command prompt.  You'll need to run it with elevated privilege, i.e., by pressing control-shift-ENTER at the Start Menu or by running it from an elevated command prompt.  The "Create standard settings" option should be appropriate; you can then select the drivers to be monitored (basically, any that you are suspicious of; all non-Microsoft drivers would often be a sensible choice).  Default verification options are applied, including pool tracking.  Since the memory you're interested in is already allocated, you'll need to reboot.

Once you've rebooted, run the Driver Verifier Manager again and select "Display information about the currently verified drivers".  Click Next until you get to the "Counters specific to each of the currently verified drivers" page and go through the drivers until you find one with lots of allocated memory.  Hopefully, it will be the driver for FancyCache.

Because kernel mode is kernel mode, I don't think that Driver Verifier will always work; it relies on the drivers following the rules, at least approximately.  There are probably various oddball methods a driver could use to allocate memory that will evade Driver Verifier's counters.  But it should work most of the time.

Comment: I just tried that, rebooted, and got a BSOD with error 0x000000C4. :(

Comment: Ouch.  Sorry about that.  (In my defense, though, I'm fairly sure that means one of the selected drivers is buggy.)  Hopefully you were able to boot to safe mode and run Driver Verifier Manager to turn verification back off again?

Comment: Haha don't worry, that's what I did. It was just funny. :-) +1, I knew this tool existed but I'd never used it (or even thought to). Seems very handy!

Comment: It might work (i.e., not trigger a bugcheck!) even with slightly buggy drivers if you use the custom option and only turn on the pool tracking without any of the other checks.

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get the chance, thanks. I'm gonna need a bit of time since I have no idea how much trial/error this is going to need. :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading up on FancyCache, at a guess I'd say that because it's a driver rather than a process, it's not going to show up in the process list directly. It does however use RAM to cache disk access, so whatever you configure it with is what's going to disappear from available memory, and perhaps windows is reporting this backwards somehow. Again, the system drivers do require some memory to do what they do, and this may not directly show up in the process list (they're not directly processes remember - you don't see drivers for your network card or video adaptor show up in the process list either, remember...)

I also note that your screenshot above shows only the Working Set size. This is only one type of memory, which is useful to describe for most processes, but may not show the whole picture in some edge cases (such as this.)

Anyway, upshot is that memory management in modern OSs is terrifyingly complex, so when you throw in a system filter driver which uses half a gig as a cache and it doesn't show up in a third party process list utility as you might expect given how applications normally show up, don't be surprised or upset - it's just how it is :)

Comment: Yes, we already determine all that in the comments above. The question is how to actually observe and measure the memory usage of a driver.

Comment: I don't know of any way you can; since the driver runs in the context of the kernel, all drivers probably share the same accounting/pool with mallocs etc. If you had something that could start at that drivers entry points and counted memory references and usage you could probably tell. I think if you force the OS to crashdump and use windbg to examine the dump file you can probably do a one off inspection, but I know nothing like task manager that would show you that info as the OS is running live. Looks like someone just answered above with a windows util that does this though, so...