# How do I precisely analyse the memory usage in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find what’s eating up all of my system’s memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/437918/how-do-i-find-whats-eating-up-all-of-my-systems-memory)

I have a machine with 4 GB of RAM and no swap because hard drive is incredibly slow and enabling it make computer nearly unusable.

I am running several processes and when I sum all memory eaten by all processes from Task Manager, it doesn't give more than 400MB of RAM (working set and private set). But still Task Manager says that 85% of memory is used, system is complaining that it's out of memory and applications are crashing as they run out of memory.

- What uses the remaining 3.5 GB of RAM?
- Is there a way to detect it?
- Analyze the kernel, drivers, caches and everything to check what precisely uses this memory so that I could disable it to free some operating memory?

I checked show all processes and system is 64 bit.

I don't believe Windows 7 kernel requires 3.5 GB of RAM for it to work... Please note I am more a Unix guy, so I don't see much into Windows. But it doesn't make much sense to me that when processes are eating 400 MB, whole 4 GB RAM is being used and system is crashing.

In Linux you can type the command `free` to see how much memory you have, how much buffers are using and how much is "physically" used by applications. Is there something like that in Windows?

Comment: You have applications or services running in the background.

Comment: 1. [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) 2. [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx) 3. [VMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx)

Comment: Win7 x32 or x64? Did you check "Show processes from all users" in Task Manager?

Comment: The SU Question [How do I find what's eating up all of my system's memory?](http://superuser.com/questions/437918/how-do-i-find-whats-eating-up-all-of-my-systems-memory) covers the exact same topic and has a lot of good answers, you may want to look there.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I am  surprised you did not close as duplicate, you are the accepted answer on the other question I linked.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Good catch! I knew this sounded familiar, but I was under tight time constraints ;)

Comment: I downloaded RAMMap, but despite it shows more than 1gb of zeroed memory, any application that requires more than 50mb of ram is terminated by system. Why?