# Extreamly high memory usage in windows 10, and no clue as to why

Tags: windows-10, memory, performance

Hello and thanks for your attention.

**The problem:**

For approximately one week my work computer's memory usage has spiked to very high level, to the point that it has almost became impossible for me to do my job when running visual studio, as visual studio is starting to suffer glitches almost every minutes and almost impossible to work with unless i close absolutely everything else, the problem of course is not just with visual studio but also with all my other apps, as in i can't open more than 6 tabs on Firefox without it crashing or even opening my mail properly. I have 8 gigabytes of ram, and i never suffered memory shortage until this last week, and Task Manager gives me no clue as to why is this happening, in fact Task Manager can only detect total of 400-500 MB ram begin used by installed softwares.

[image: Processes sorted by memory usage]

[image: Performance and resource monitor]

[image: total memory usage detected by task manger]

**what i have tried:**

the first thing i did was to try closing/disabling some of my usually high memory using software, including:

- Cortana
- Skype
- BitDefender Active Shield
- Nord vpn

and few other less usually problematic softwares, however none of them fixed it.

Then i tried scanning for viruses using BitDefender and then trying it's One Click optimization, no result. I almost crashed my computer cuz of high memory usage.

I tried the "Adjust for best performance" in Advanced Computer settings > performance. Only had a small slight improvement but things are still not looking good.

I also tried running [poolmon](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2012/08/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon/) to see if i have memory leak, ironically, it stopped little after start due to low memory XD

I defraged all my hard drives.

I tried updating drivers using "search online" but windows thinks all my drivers are up to date.

I restarted my computer after i turned off all the startup programs that i could. also no luck.

I am running out of options here and i really rather not do something like reinstalling my windows because right now i am very busy with a project and have to keep up with a deadline, thankfully i can do it with VS code for now. But i still would rather have my system fixed so i can get back to Visual studio. do you guys know how can i fix the problem, or to find out what is causing the high memory usage in my system?

Comment: Is this happening when booting in Safe mode? You can use [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) to analyze memory usage. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/437925/8672).

Comment: You have a non-paged pool leak.