# Lenovo Ideacentre 3 always uses on average above 70% ram (even after an upgrade from 4 Go ram to 8 Go

Tags: windows-10, memory

I'm presently using a Lenovo Ideacentre 3 07ADA05, AMD 3020e with Radeon Graphics               1.20 GHz, under windows 10 and I upgraded the ram from 4 Go to 8 Go. But for unknown reasons its displayed 8 Go and only 5.94 Go usable (cf screenshots below) and average of 70% of this last is all the time in use even I don't run a lot of applications. I need to make sure that my applications in development can use at least 5 Go of the ram.
[image]
[image]

The processes running are the below :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're probably reserving 2GB for the onboard graphics. You can change this in the BIOS/UEFI or sometimes via a tool from Lenovo. As for windows showing 70% RAM usage: you can see 1.6GB of that is just cached and can be freed for any app that needs it. Secondly we cant see what processes you are running, so its impossible to tell if any of them are hogging ram. Overall, your system seems to be running correctly.

Comment: If your app uses more memory than you have available, it will use the Page file for swapping in and out.

Comment: I've just added screenshots of my average running processes.

Comment: its completely normal. Windows 10 is designed to keep everything in memory which could be useful, even if currently you're not using it. You have to take a look at resource monitor, not task manager. Any memory which is not reported as "in use" can be freed up at any moment. see also [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/437925/714576) which should answer most of your question